# Which is better and faster ? Wordpress Queries or SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Suppose I am developing a minimal theme, the the post page `single.php` displays only the post title, the excerpt and the content.

So in general that would be

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

So I am expecting 3 queries...

Instead if I write a custom query where I am just fetching these 3 datas in an array at once...

```
<?php arr[] = get_row(select title, excerpt, content from wp_posts where post_id = 1); ?>
<?php echo arr[0] ?>
<?php echo arr[1] ?>
<?php echo arr[2] ?>
```

Which is faster or does it make a difference ?

Plz ignore syntax if wrong...

Comment: You can easily test which is faster by doing a little benchmark on a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title` function usage path is

the_title > get_the_title > get_post > WP_Post

At the end, WP_Post get_instance method has following lines

```
$_post = wp_cache_get( $post_id, 'posts' );

if ( ! $_post ) {
    $_post = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d LIMIT 1", $post_id ) );

    if ( ! $_post )
        return false;

    $_post = sanitize_post( $_post, 'raw' );
    wp_cache_add( $_post->ID, $_post, 'posts' );
} elseif ( empty( $_post->filter ) ) {
    $_post = sanitize_post( $_post, 'raw' );
}
```

So, the_title use get_row method. And it's is `SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d LIMIT 1` and yours is `select title, excerpt, content from wp_posts where post_id = 1`. maybe you can add `LIMIT 1` to your sql code.

But `wp_cache_get` is the difference of these all things. Cache will change everythings if it works good.